# Different results in calculating Variance ans Standard Deviation in R

Tags: r, statistics, variance, deviation

Calculating variance and standard deviation based on the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) description gives different results compared to the standard functions **var()** and **sd()** in R.

Variance: 4 versus 4.571429. Standard deviation: 2 versus 2.13809.

*Anyone suggestions or an explanation?*

```
> df <- c(2,4,4,4,5,5,7,9)
> df.length <- length(df)
> df.length
[1] 8

> df.mean <- sum(df) / df.length
> df.mean
[1] 5

> df.difference <- (df - df.mean)**2
> df.difference
[1]  9  1  1  1  0  0  4 16

> sum(df.difference)
[1] 32

> df.variance <- sum(df.difference) / df.length
> df.variance
[1] 4

> df.standard.deviation <- sqrt(df.variance)
> df.standard.deviation
[1] 2

> # mean, var and sd (default R)

> mean(df)
[1] 5

> var(df)
[1] 4.571429

> sd(df)
[1] 2.13809
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the difference between dividing by `n` or `(n-1)` degrees of freedom.

```
>df <- c(2,4,4,4,5,5,7,9)
> var(df)
[1] 4.571429


> sum((df-mean(df))^2/length(df))
[1] 4

> sum((df-mean(df))^2/(length(df)-1))
[1] 4.571429
```

It's `n-1` because ... copied straight from Wikipedia ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_%28statistics%29))

> A common way to think of degrees of freedom is as the number of
>   independent pieces of information available to estimate another piece
>   of information. More concretely, the number of degrees of freedom is
>   the number of independent observations in a sample of data that are
>   available to estimate a parameter of the population from which that
>   sample is drawn. For example, if we have two observations, when
>   calculating the mean we have two independent observations; however,
>   when calculating the variance, we have only one independent
>   observation, since the two observations are equally distant from the
>   mean.

Comment: Thnx! I found some additional information on this subject: [PDF](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&ved=0CG4QFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdigitalcommons.unl.edu%2Fcgi%2Fviewcontent.cgi%3Farticle%3D1008%26context%3Dimseteach&ei=Qnq1UrvRM-KQ0AWdl4DQDQ&usg=AFQjCNErI6wFPfD2oz9xVu_1E6EQ37sGpA&sig2=zyts5YqTDGbXjEFC9LDKvA&bvm=bv.58187178,d.d2k) and [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92s7IVS6A34).